# PayPal API GetVerifiedStatus not working

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

So I've been trying to implement PayPal's GetVerifiedStatus API into my website but have been running into the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PayPal\Types\AA\GetVerifiedStatusRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\paypaltest\getversys.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\paypaltest\getversys.php on line 14`

What could the problem be? What I was able to figure out was that that particular directory is missing. But I have no idea as to how to get it because I've looked for it without any success.

I've been using exactly the same code as given by the PayPal SDK. Here it is:

```
<?php
use PayPal\Service\AdaptiveAccountsService;
use PayPal\Types\AA\AccountIdentifierType;
use PayPal\Types\AA\GetVerifiedStatusRequest;
require_once('bootstrap.php');
$getVerifiedStatus = new GetVerifiedStatusRequest();


$accountIdentifier=new AccountIdentifierType();


$accountIdentifier->emailAddress = $_REQUEST['emailAddress'];
$getVerifiedStatus->accountIdentifier=$accountIdentifier;


$getVerifiedStatus->firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];


$getVerifiedStatus->lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
$getVerifiedStatus->matchCriteria = $_REQUEST['matchCriteria'];


$service  = new AdaptiveAccountsService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {

    $response = $service->GetVerifiedStatus($getVerifiedStatus);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    require_once 'Common/Error.php';
    exit;
} 

$ack = strtoupper($response->responseEnvelope->ack);
if($ack != "SUCCESS"){
    echo "<b>Error </b>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";      
} else {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Ack :</td><td><div id='Ack'>$ack</div> </td></tr>";
echo "</table>";        
}


require_once 'Common/Response.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question here because I contacted PayPal tech support and was told that the `GetVerifiedStatus` API is now deprecated and can't be used.

This is the reason for the error.